# fabric invoke chaincode error: Failed to get endorsing peers: no endorsement combination can be satisfied

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-go

I have set up my fabric network with 3 orderers in one organization and a consortium with 5 organizaitons successfully. Each organization has only one peer node and join in the same channel. And I have installed and instantiated two chaincodes in this channel. However, when I invoke chaincode by *channel.Client, sometimes it work correctly, and sometimes I get such an error:

```sh
Failed to get endorsing peers: Discovery status Code: (11) UNKNOWN. Description: error getting endorsers: no endorsement combination can be satisfied
```

this's my dev environment:

```
# os
Darwin PANZVORHONG-MB0 20.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 20.3.0: Thu Jan 21 00:07:06 PST 2021; root:xnu-7195.81.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
# golang
go version go1.15.6 darwin/amd64
# docker
Engine Version: 20.10.5
```

The following is same the configuration of Fabric which I think may be useful:
configtx.yaml

```yaml
Organizations:
  - &OrdererOrg
    Name: OrdererMSP
    ID: OrdererMSP
    MSPDir: ../fabric/organizations/ordererOrganizations/food.com/msp
    Policies:
      Readers:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
      Writers:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
      Admins:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.admin')"
    OrdererEndpoints:
      - orderer1.food.com:7050
      - orderer2.food.com:7049
      - orderer3.food.com:7048

  - &Producer
    Name: ProducerMSP
    ID: ProducerMSP
    MSPDir: ../fabric/organizations/peerOrganizations/producer.food.com/msp
    Policies:
      Readers:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('ProducerMSP.admin', 'ProducerMSP.peer', 'ProducerMSP.client')"
      Writers:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('ProducerMSP.admin', 'ProducerMSP.client')"
      Admins:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('ProducerMSP.admin')"
      Endorsement:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('ProducerMSP.peer')"
    AnchorPeers:
      - Host: peer0.producer.food.com
        Port: 7051

  - &Processor
    Name: ProcessorMSP
    ID: ProcessorMSP
    MSPDir: ../fabric/organizations/peerOrganizations/processor.food.com/msp
    Policies:
      Readers:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('ProcessorMSP.admin', 'ProcessorMSP.peer', 'ProcessorMSP.client')"
      Writers:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('ProcessorMSP.admin', 'ProcessorMSP.client')"
      Admins:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('ProcessorMSP.admin')"
      Endorsement:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('ProcessorMSP.peer')"

    AnchorPeers:
      - Host: peer0.processor.food.com
        Port: 7051

...Similar configuration of other nodes
```

docker-compose.yaml

```yaml
peer0.producer.food.com:
    container_name: peer0.producer.food.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=food
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_NETWORKID=food
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
      # Peer specific variabes
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.producer.food.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.producer.food.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.producer.food.com:7052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7052
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.producer.food.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.producer.food.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=ProducerMSP
      - GODEBUG=netdns=go
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/host/var/run/docker.sock
      - ../fabric/organizations/peerOrganizations/producer.food.com/peers/peer0.producer.food.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
      - ../fabric/organizations/peerOrganizations/producer.food.com/peers/peer0.producer.food.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
      - peer0.producer.food.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer node start
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
    networks:
      - food

  peer0.processor.food.com:
    container_name: peer0.processor.food.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=food
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_NETWORKID=food
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
      # Peer specific variabes
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.processor.food.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.processor.food.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.processor.food.com:7052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7052
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.processor.food.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.processor.food.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=ProcessorMSP
      - GODEBUG=netdns=go
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/host/var/run/docker.sock
      - ../fabric/organizations/peerOrganizations/processor.food.com/peers/peer0.processor.food.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
      - ../fabric/organizations/peerOrganizations/processor.food.com/peers/peer0.processor.food.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
      - peer0.processor.food.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer node start
    ports:
      - 9051:7051
    networks:
      - food

...Similar configuration of other nodes
```

config.yaml for `fabric-sdk-go`:

```yaml
channels:
  food-channel:
    peers:
      peer0.producer.food.com:
        endorsingPeer: true
        chaincodeQuery: true
        ledgerQuery: true
        eventSource: true

      peer0.processor.food.com:
        endorsingPeer: true
        chaincodeQuery: true
        ledgerQuery: true
        eventSource: true
......

policies:
      queryChannelConfig:
        minResponses: 1
        maxTargets: 1
        retryOpts:
          attempts: 5
          initialBackoff: 500ms
          maxBackoff: 5s
          backoffFactor: 2.0
      discovery:
        maxTargets: 1
        retryOpts:
          attempts: 4
          initialBackoff: 500ms
          maxBackoff: 5s
          backoffFactor: 2.0
      eventService:
        resolverStrategy: PreferOrg
        balancer: Random
        blockHeightLagThreshold: 5
        reconnectBlockHeightLagThreshold: 10
        peerMonitorPeriod: 5s

......

organizations:
  producer:
    mspid: ProducerMSP

    # This org's MSP store (absolute path or relative to client.cryptoconfig)
    cryptoPath: peerOrganizations/producer.food.com/users/{username}@producer.food.com/msp

    peers:
      - peer0.producer.food.com
  processor:
    mspid: ProcessorMSP
    cryptoPath: peerOrganizations/processor.food.com/users/{username}@processor.food.com/msp
    peers:
      - peer0.processor.food.com

  transporter:
    mspid: TransporterMSP
......

peers:
  peer0.producer.food.com:
    url: localhost:7051
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer0.producer.food.com
      keep-alive-time: 5s
      keep-alive-timeout: 20s
      keep-alive-permit: false
      fail-fast: false
      allow-insecure: false

    tlsCACerts:
      path: ./fixtures/fabric/organizations/peerOrganizations/producer.food.com/tlsca/tlsca.producer.food.com-cert.pem

......

entityMatchers:
  peer:
    # the below matcher will allow dynamic discovery to use the anchor peer (peer0.org1.example.com)
    # as a template for all org1 discovered peers config
    - pattern: (\w+).producer.food.com:(\d+)
      urlSubstitutionExp: localhost:7051
      sslTargetOverrideUrlSubstitutionExp: ${1}.producer.food.com
      mappedHost: peer0.producer.food.com

    - pattern: (\w+).processor.food.com:(\d+)
      urlSubstitutionExp: localhost:9051
      sslTargetOverrideUrlSubstitutionExp: ${1}.processor.food.com
      mappedHost: peer0.processor.food.com

    - pattern: (\w+).transporter.food.com:(\d+)
      urlSubstitutionExp: localhost:7061
      sslTargetOverrideUrlSubstitutionExp: ${1}.transporter.food.com
      mappedHost: peer0.transporter.food.com

    - pattern: (\w+).seller.food.com:(\d+)
      urlSubstitutionExp: localhost:7071
      sslTargetOverrideUrlSubstitutionExp: ${1}.seller.food.com
      mappedHost: peer0.seller.food.com

    - pattern: (\w+).consumer.food.com:(\d+)
      urlSubstitutionExp: localhost:7081
      sslTargetOverrideUrlSubstitutionExp: ${1}.consumer.food.com
      mappedHost: peer0.consumer.food.com
  orderer:
    - pattern: (\w+).food.com:(\d+)
      urlSubstitutionExp: localhost:7050
      sslTargetOverrideUrlSubstitutionExp: orderer1.food.com
      mappedHost: orderer1.food.com
    - pattern: (\w+).food.com:(\d+)
      urlSubstitutionExp: localhost:7049
      sslTargetOverrideUrlSubstitutionExp: orderer2.food.com
      mappedHost: orderer2.food.com
    - pattern: (\w+).food.com:(\d+)
      urlSubstitutionExp: localhost:7048
      sslTargetOverrideUrlSubstitutionExp: orderer3.food.com
      mappedHost: orderer3.food.com
```

I've been troubled by this problem for a long time. Can someone help me?

---

I have found the reason for this problem. That's because endorsers got from channel should be contained in the peers list which got by `discovery`, or it will be filtered.
And there has always been only one endorser peer got from channel or `discovery`. So, unless the two are equal, the endorsement is not satisfied. As a result, it may take several retries to succeed, or an error will be returned when the `channel.policies.discovery.retryOpts.attempts` or `channel.policies.discovery.retryOpts.maxBackoff` is reached.

Now the question is, why can only one endorser be obtained from the channel or found by `discovery`? I tried to fix it by modifying some possible configurations in yaml, but they all failed.

[image: debug msg]

Answer (score 0):

In the config.yaml in the `peers` section, you specified only a single peer `peer0.producer.food.com`, add `peer0.processor.food.com` there as well and sdk won't ignore it anymore. To understand why it's ignored you can enable debug logs in the SDK.